# CALayer.h Semantic Issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, calayer

I'm having a ton of error of Semantic Issue coming from CALayer.h, any idea why this could be happening? Here an description image.

[image: CALayer.h Semantic Issue]

Comment: When did you get these errors ? Are you getting the errors in a newly created project ?

Comment: Where and how have you imported it in your code?

Comment: Import QuartzCore.framework